# Select into List<int> from grouped objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I select into a list of integers from the following code select grouped by `McID`?

```
machinesVisited.GroupBy(x=> x.McID).
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = machinesVisited.GroupBy(x=> x.McID).Select(g=>g.Key).ToList();
```